# Understanding log-log axes

Tags: bode-plot, log

In below  picture there are two graphs representing the function \$H(s) = s-z_1\$ (assume \$z_1=2\$ is a constant).

The left graph has \$\omega\$ on x axis and \$\|H(j\omega)\|\$ on y axis.
The right graph has \$\log\dfrac{\omega}{\|z_1\|}\$ on x axis and \$\log\dfrac{\| H(j\omega)\| }{\|z_1\|}\$ on y axis.

I completely understand the left graph. I don't understand how they got the right graph. I get why \$\|H(j\omega)\|\$ approaches \$\|z_1\|\$ as \$\omega \to 0\$, and I get why \$\|H(j\omega)\|\$ approaches \$\omega\$ as \$\omega \to \infty\$. ***But what happened to the graph for \$\omega \lt 0\$ ?*** I don't see it in the right graph ? 
[image]

EDIT :  Kindly bear with the poor quality screenshot. Looks MIT folks have compressed too much these videos...  Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/2X7o37pfdp8?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61kdPAOC7CzFjJZ8f1eMUxs&t=795) from which I took this screenshot

Comment: Consider using the snipping tool if you're using Windows. Your picture is a little fuzzy.

Comment: "a little" is "barely readable".

Comment: @MarcusMüller, are you on a phone? On a desktop it's a bit fuzzy but clear enough to convey what's needed to answer the question.

Comment: Desktop with less than optimally backlit screen; the fact that OP actually used a flash kind of kicked this from "was a little careless when supplying info" to "oh, come on, you can do better than that with this much reputation"

Comment: Sorry friends I don't mean to be careless, actual quality of the youtube video itself is poor. I can point the video if you want ?

Comment: Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/2X7o37pfdp8?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61kdPAOC7CzFjJZ8f1eMUxs&t=795) from which I took the screenshot

Answer (score 3):

> But what happened to the graph for ω < 0 ?

A log scaled axis can't show the range \$\omega < 0\$, because the logarithm function isn't defined (or if you do define it, isn't real valued) for arguments less than or equal to zero.

If this is a real filter (real-valued inputs and outputs) then you know that the response to negative frequencies is the complex conjugate of the response to positive frequencies, so graphing the negative frequencies doesn't give you any new information and isn't necessary.

Comment: Ohk... right side graph is only for \$\omega \gt 0\$, then I guess it makes sense... when \$\omega = |z_1|10^{-2}\$ etc the x values get negative, but the y value stays around \$0\$ because \$\log \dfrac{\|H(j\omega)\|}{\|z_1\|} \approx \log \dfrac{\|z_1\|}{\|z_1\|} = 0\$. I think I get this. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have a small question, why are they using \$\log \dfrac{\omega}{\|z_1\|}\$ on x axis ? Because, for the magnitude we have $$\|H(j\omega)\| = \sqrt{\omega^2+4}=2\sqrt{(\omega/2)^2+1}$$ Taking log both sides and rearranging gives $$\color{blue}{\log \dfrac{\|H(j\omega)\|}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{2}\color{red}{\log((\omega/2)^2+1)}$$

Comment: This is of form $$\color{blue}{y} = \dfrac{1}{2}\color{red}{x}$$

shouldn't we be letting \$\color{red}{x=\log((\omega/2)^2+1)}\$ instead ?